# /wi/ sound in cuisine

Tags: pronunciation

The word *cuisine*, like *quick*, starts with the sound /kwɪ/. However they are pronounced differently (or I hear them so): /ɪ/ is not pronounced in the former at all. I checked it both in a learner's dictionary ([+](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cuisine?q=cuisine)), and in a dictionary for native speakers ([+](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/cuisine)).

Am I missing the /ɪ/ sound in the pronunciation of *cuisine*, or are the pronunciations incorrect?

Comment: "Cuisine" is basically a French word, used in English to sound sophisticated.  How someone pronounces it depends to a great degree on how much French they know.

Comment: The OED has /kwiːˈziːn/ and /kwɪk/. Note the longer "i" sound in the former. This probably what you are hearing.
,

Comment: @Greybeard Have you ever heard someone who isn’t French pronounce both syllables of *cuisine* in English using identical /i/ vowels in both syllables, [the ‹ɪj›   diphthong](https://www.englishspeechservices.com/blog/the-fallac%c9%aajof-schwee/) of *queen* or *fleece*? Me, I have not.

Comment: @tchrist I agree, in broad terms, with your para 4 in the answer below. Allowing for the number of vowel sounds that the "i" of cuisine might produce from people with various accents and knowledge of, and ability with, French, it would be hard to be definite or prescriptive on the first "i".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot but wonder how you hear (read: perceive) *cuisine* being pronounced. When I listen to your two sources’ sound clips, I hear both using phonemic /ɪ/ for their unstressed vowel, sometimes shorter than other times.

In English, *cuisine* is phonemically /kwɪˈzin/, meaning that the first vowel is the KIT vowel but the second is the FLEECE vowel. In French, both are closer to the English FLEECE vowel, and there is no aspiration of the initial /k/.

So someone affecting a French accent in English *might* make them both the same, but otherwise you would not normally do so.

Because the first vowel is unstressed, it is subject to the [customary reduction such vowels suffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_and_vowel_reduction_in_English#Reduced_vowels_in_the_close_unrounded_area) in English, producing a [wide possible range of phonetic realizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects) in which phonemic /ɪ/ becomes any of [ɪ̈], [ɨ̞], or [ə] phonetically.

If you cannot hear any difference between the unstressed vowels of *roses* 
and *Rosa’s*, then you or those you're listening to may have the [weak vowel merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_close_front_vowels#Weak_vowel_merger).
You’ll also find wide variation in [the unstressed vowel of *naked*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/naked) along those same lines.

If you yourself cannot normally perceive *sheep*’s /i/ from *ship*’s /ɪ/, then you are like a great many who come to English with backgrounds in other languages which lack that particular phonemic distinction.

Comment: "I cannot but wonder how you hear ...". I hear /kwi/ in _cuisine_ almost similar to /kʊ/ in _pincushion_ as pronounced in the Google Dictionary (i.e. the box that appears in the search results when you search _definition xyz_) (I should add that although its data is provided by OED, the pronunciation in the latter website is different)

Comment: @Kaveh That rather reminds me of the notorious "Fush-n-Chups" vowel shift found in some native speakers from New Zealand.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603199/2085).